# Run sudo command with non-root user in Docker container

Tags: bash, sudo, docker

I have this Dockerfile:

```
FROM ubuntu:17.04

# Must have packages
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y nano zsh curl git

# Instal Oh my Zsh
RUN bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh/master/tools/install.sh)"
RUN sed -i -- 's/robbyrussell/sonicradish/g' /root/.zshrc 

# Add none root user
RUN adduser admin
USER admin
```

I'm connecting with the admin user with the zsh shell.

```
docker exec -ti linux zsh
```

I'm adding a non-root user (admin).

I still want to execute a `sudo` command with this user, but it errors out:

```
$ sudo apt-get install vim
zsh: command not found: sudo
```

Same message with bash shell.

How can I run `sudo` commands with a non-root user?

When I don't use `sudo` I get a permission error:

```
$ apt-get install vim
E: Could not open lock file /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (13: Permission denied)
E: Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/), are you root?
```

Comment: I'm not that much familiar with docker,  aren't you able to use root in image? can you add the output of `which sudo` to your question?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is what I would do

```
FROM ubuntu:17.04

# Must have packages
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y vim nano zsh curl git sudo

# Install Oh my Zsh
RUN bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh/master/tools/install.sh)"
RUN sed -i -- 's/robbyrussell/sonicradish/g' /root/.zshrc 

# Add none root user
RUN  useradd admin && echo "admin:admin" | chpasswd && adduser admin sudo
USER admin
```

Comment: You can not run sudo in Dockerfile. It does not work :( ... even when I remove the sudo command

Comment: Kevin, sorry I wasn't able to test docker before. Can you retry with the new example?

Comment: Still the same messages :(

Comment: The `command not found` or that Docker can't run sudo?

Comment: I have updated my post to show the specific message for each command

Comment: Sorry I did not see you install also sudo before. it works that way

Answer (score 4):

Just create your non root user and add it to the **sudoers** group:

```
FROM ubuntu:17.04

RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install sudo

RUN adduser --disabled-password --gecos '' admin
RUN adduser admin sudo
RUN echo '%sudo ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL' >> /etc/sudoers

USER admin
```